# grails dbm-update sometimes gives an groovy.lang.MissingMethodException

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-orm, database-migration, liquibase

I'm using Grails migration, and sometimes the dbm-update works and other don't.

I'm recieving the error:

```
Command execution error: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: Script1.databaseChangeLog() is applicable for argument types: (Script1$_run_closure1) values: [Script1$_run_closure1@4dafab49]
```

I tried to debug and analyze. I got some logs, but I wasn't able to discover anything.

logs:

```
13:08:24.739 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] * Exception is:
13:08:24.739 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':dbmUpdate'.
13:08:24.739 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$3.accept(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:166)
13:08:24.739 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$3.accept(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:163)
13:08:24.740 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.Try$Failure.ifSuccessfulOrElse(Try.java:191)
13:08:24.740 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:156)
13:08:24.740 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:62)
13:08:24.740 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:108)
13:08:24.740 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveBeforeExecutionOutputsTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveBeforeExecutionOutputsTaskExecuter.java:67)
13:08:24.740 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.StartSnapshotTaskInputsBuildOperationTaskExecuter.execute(StartSnapshotTaskInputsBuildOperationTaskExecuter.java:62)
13:08:24.740 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveAfterPreviousExecutionStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveAfterPreviousExecutionStateTaskExecuter.java:46)
13:08:24.740 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:94)
13:08:24.740 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:46)
13:08:24.740 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.java:95)
13:08:24.740 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:57)
13:08:24.740 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:56)
13:08:24.740 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:36)
13:08:24.740 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.executeTask(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:77)
13:08:24.740 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:55)
13:08:24.740 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
13:08:24.740 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:416)
13:08:24.740 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:406)
13:08:24.740 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:165)
13:08:24.740 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:250)
13:08:24.740 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:158)
13:08:24.740 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:102)
13:08:24.740 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.call(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:36)
13:08:24.740 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
13:08:24.740 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.execution.plan.LocalTaskNodeExecutor.execute(LocalTaskNodeExecutor.java:43)
13:08:24.740 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:355)
13:08:24.740 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:343)
13:08:24.740 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:336)
13:08:24.740 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:322)
13:08:24.740 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:134)
13:08:24.740 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:129)
13:08:24.740 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:202)
13:08:24.740 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.executeNextNode(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:193)
13:08:24.740 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:129)
13:08:24.740 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
13:08:24.740 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
13:08:24.740 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
13:08:24.740 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
13:08:24.740 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:56)
13:08:24.740 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
13:08:24.740 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] Caused by: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
13:08:24.740 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle$ExecResultImpl.assertNormalExitValue(DefaultExecHandle.java:409)
13:08:24.740 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultJavaExecAction.execute(DefaultJavaExecAction.java:40)
13:08:24.740 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.tasks.JavaExec.exec(JavaExec.java:121)
13:08:24.740 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor747.invoke(Unknown Source)
13:08:24.740 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
13:08:24.740 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
13:08:24.740 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:103)
13:08:24.740 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.doExecute(StandardTaskAction.java:49)
13:08:24.740 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:42)
13:08:24.740 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:28)
13:08:24.740 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:717)
13:08:24.740 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:684)
13:08:24.740 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$5.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:476)
13:08:24.740 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:402)
13:08:24.741 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:394)
13:08:24.741 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:165)
13:08:24.741 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:250)
13:08:24.741 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:158)
13:08:24.741 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:92)
13:08:24.741 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
13:08:24.741 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:461)
13:08:24.741 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:444)
13:08:24.741 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.access$200(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:93)
13:08:24.741 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$TaskExecution.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:237)
13:08:24.741 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.lambda$execute$1(ExecuteStep.java:33)
13:08:24.741 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:369)
13:08:24.741 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.execute(ExecuteStep.java:33)
13:08:24.741 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.execute(ExecuteStep.java:26)
13:08:24.741 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CleanupOutputsStep.execute(CleanupOutputsStep.java:58)
13:08:24.741 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CleanupOutputsStep.execute(CleanupOutputsStep.java:35)
13:08:24.741 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveInputChangesStep.execute(ResolveInputChangesStep.java:48)
13:08:24.741 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveInputChangesStep.execute(ResolveInputChangesStep.java:33)
13:08:24.741 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CancelExecutionStep.execute(CancelExecutionStep.java:39)
13:08:24.741 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.TimeoutStep.executeWithoutTimeout(TimeoutStep.java:73)
13:08:24.741 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.TimeoutStep.execute(TimeoutStep.java:54)
13:08:24.741 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CatchExceptionStep.execute(CatchExceptionStep.java:35)
13:08:24.741 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CreateOutputsStep.execute(CreateOutputsStep.java:51)
13:08:24.741 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SnapshotOutputsStep.execute(SnapshotOutputsStep.java:45)
13:08:24.741 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SnapshotOutputsStep.execute(SnapshotOutputsStep.java:31)
13:08:24.741 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CacheStep.executeWithoutCache(CacheStep.java:208)
13:08:24.741 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CacheStep.execute(CacheStep.java:70)
13:08:24.741 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CacheStep.execute(CacheStep.java:45)
13:08:24.741 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BroadcastChangingOutputsStep.execute(BroadcastChangingOutputsStep.java:49)
13:08:24.741 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.StoreSnapshotsStep.execute(StoreSnapshotsStep.java:43)
13:08:24.741 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.StoreSnapshotsStep.execute(StoreSnapshotsStep.java:32)
13:08:24.741 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RecordOutputsStep.execute(RecordOutputsStep.java:38)
13:08:24.741 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RecordOutputsStep.execute(RecordOutputsStep.java:24)
13:08:24.741 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.executeBecause(SkipUpToDateStep.java:96)
13:08:24.741 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.lambda$execute$0(SkipUpToDateStep.java:89)
13:08:24.741 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at java.base/java.util.Optional.map(Optional.java:265)
13:08:24.741 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.execute(SkipUpToDateStep.java:54)
13:08:24.741 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.execute(SkipUpToDateStep.java:38)
13:08:24.741 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveChangesStep.execute(ResolveChangesStep.java:76)
13:08:24.741 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveChangesStep.execute(ResolveChangesStep.java:37)
13:08:24.741 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.java:36)
13:08:24.741 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.java:26)
13:08:24.741 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveCachingStateStep.execute(ResolveCachingStateStep.java:90)
13:08:24.741 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveCachingStateStep.execute(ResolveCachingStateStep.java:48)
13:08:24.741 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.execute(CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.java:69)
13:08:24.741 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.execute(CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.java:47)
13:08:24.741 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.DefaultWorkExecutor.execute(DefaultWorkExecutor.java:33)
13:08:24.741 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:140)
13:08:24.741 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   ... 38 more
13:08:24.741 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] 
13:08:24.741 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] 
13:08:24.741 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
13:08:24.741 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildResultLogger] 
13:08:24.741 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildResultLogger] BUILD FAILED in 10s
13:08:24.741 [LIFECYCLE] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.TaskExecutionStatisticsReporter] 5 actionable tasks: 2 executed, 3 up-to-date
```

My changelog.groovy:

```
databaseChangeLog {
  changeSet(id: "202010031905-1", author: "Breno S. e Alves", runOnChange: "true") {
    sqlFile(path: "sql/identity_provider/create_database.sql", splitStatements: false, endDelimiter: ";")
  }

  changeSet(id: "202010031905-2", author: "Breno S. e Alves", runOnChange: "true") {
    sqlFile(path: "sql/identity_provider/create_triggers.sql", splitStatements: true, endDelimiter: "\nGO", stripComments: false)
  }

  changeSet(id: "202010031905-3", author: "Breno S. e Alves", runOnChange: "true") {
    sqlFile(path: "sql/identity_provider/alter_data.sql", splitStatements: false, endDelimiter: ";")
  }

}
```

I'm using:

- Grails Version: 4.0.1
- JVM Version: 11.0.9
- Groovy version: 3.0.4
- Liquibase version: 3.10.2
- Liquibase gradle plugin version: 2.0.4
- Liquibase DSL version: 2.2.1
- Grails Database Migration Version: 3.1.0

Does anyone knows what this could possibly be? It's strange because like 1 in 3 runs this errors occurs.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: FYI... We don't support Groovy 3.0.4 with Grails 4.0.1.  We will introduce support for Groovy 3 with Grails 4.1.

Comment: Oh.... you think that maybe this error is related to this  dependency problem? I haven't had any problem with this AFAIK.
Thanks.